# iPhone - PullDownToRefresh

Tags: iphone, uitableview, pull-to-refresh

i want to implement the feature PullDownToRefresh like Twitter app. I'm using EGORefreshTableHeaderView and PullToRefreshTableView classes, but i've an error in this point in PullToRefreshTableView.m class :

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 

if (scrollView.isDragging) {
    /*here is the error/* if (refreshHeaderView.state == EGOOPullRefreshPulling && scrollView.contentOffset.y > -65.0f && scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0.0f && !_reloading) {
        [refreshHeaderView setState:EGOOPullRefreshNormal];
    } else if (refreshHeaderView.state == EGOOPullRefreshNormal && scrollView.contentOffset.y < -65.0f && !_reloading) {
        [refreshHeaderView setState:EGOOPullRefreshPulling];
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this cool plugin from Leah. It's called [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/leah/PullToRefresh) and is hosted on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

```
You dont have to write a code inside table view controller's method
'- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView'.
Instead, just call the super class's method
'[_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];'
So, your code must look like this:- 

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{ 

    [_refreshHeaderView egoRefreshScrollViewDidScroll:scrollView];

}

download the demo  here and learn from it.
- Regards,
Rickie
```